# VBA Vlookup returns wrong results

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am currently trying to make a application where I can store sales in a single worksheet while using VBA.

When I try to use Vlookup to determine ProductID's prices so that I don't have to enter the value in myself the Vlookup returns always the same value "2015"

I have no clue where it's going wrong

This is the layout of the Sheet : [Layout](http://prntscr.com/b40ert)
This is the layout of my Userform : [Layout](http://prntscr.com/b40f4l)

And this is the code I use on my commandbutton :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim r As Range

Dim Productprijs As Integer
Dim productaantal As Integer
Dim Eindprijs As Integer



Sheet1.Activate

emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = TextBox3.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = TextBox4.Value

Productprijs = CInt(Application.VLookup(TextBox3.Value, "J2:L2000", 3, False))
productaantal = TextBox2.Value
Eindprijs = Productprijs * productaantal
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Eindprijs


UserForm1.Hide
```

Could someone help me with my problem? it might just be a minor thing I am currently overlooking.

Thanks in regards,
Martijn

Comment: try to replace `Productprijs = CInt(Application.VLookup(TextBox3.Value, "J2:L2000", 3, False))` with `Productprijs = CInt(Range("L" & Application.Match(TextBox3.Value, Range("J:J"), 0)))`

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 problems with your code;
"J2:L2000" should be replaced with Range("J2:L2000") (the 2015 is the integer version of the 2015 error)

Your code will not work if the Vlookup cannot find Textbox3.Value: in that case it will return an error: the code should look more like this

```
Sub testv()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    v = Application.VLookup(9, Range("A1:a3"), 1, False)
    If Not IsError(v) Then
        i = CLng(v)
    Else
        MsgBox "not Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is throwing a "2015 Error" because you are putting the `TextBox3.Value` *inside* the `VLookup` function as the first argument. Note that the following code works:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim emptyRow As Long
    Dim Price As Variant
    Dim Quantity As Double
    Dim Total As Double
    Dim x As Double

    'This finds the next empty row in the first table
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

    'Place the new values from the UserForm to the table
    Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value 'Date
    Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value 'Quantity
    Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = TextBox3.Value 'ProductID
    Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = TextBox4.Value 'Customer

    'Assign the value of the ProductID text box to x
    x = TextBox3.Value

    'Calculate the total price, using x instead of TextBox3.Value
    Price = Application.VLookup(x, Range("J2:L3"), 3, False)

    Quantity = TextBox2.Value
    Total = Price * Quantity
    Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Total

    UserForm1.Hide 
End Sub
```

This also eliminates the need to convert your Price variable using `CInt`. Hopefully someone else can articulate why the `TextBox3.Value` inside the `VLookup` throws an error?